# Red5 RTMPT over RTMPTS

Tags: https, red5

I have a `RED5` server and I want to stream using `RTMPT` but over the `HTTPS` / `RTMPS` protocol.
Previously I just used `rtmpt://<hostname>:5080/vod/myvideo.flv`. I assumed that by using `rtmpt://<hostname>:5443/vod/myvideo.flv` it would try using `HTTPS`, since `5080` is the `HTTP` and `5443` is the `HTTPS` port. This didn't work however.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure the handler for port 5443, see this blog entry: https://red5pro.com/docs/server/red5prossl/index.html
You'll also need an SSL cert and a domain; self-signed wont work. Also there is no RTMPTS, it is just RTMPS (tunneling) which is RTMPT over HTTPS and RTMPS (native) uses RTMP via TLS.